# Using UISearchbar with JSON to filter the result

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I am fetching the data from JSON using http in the following code:

I have an ObjectModel, DownloadModelProtocol, and TableViewController

(Modal.swift)

```
class OrderItemModal: NSObject {
    var deptname: String!
    var staffname: String!
    var status: String!
    var userid: String!
}
```

(DownloadOrderModal.swift):

```
protocol OrderDownloadProtocol: class {
    func itemsDownload(items: Array<Any>)
}    
...
let bmsOrders = NSMutableArray()
...

weak var delegate: OrderDownloadProtocol!
let urlPath = "http://localhost/production/api/db_orders.php"

func downloadItems() {
    let url = URL(string: urlPath)!
    let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
...

    for i in 0..<jsonResult.count
    {
        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary
        let bmsOrder = OrderItemModal()
....
bmsOrders.add(bmsOrder)
....
```

---

declaration:

```
var orderItems =  [OrderItemModal]()
var filterArray= [OrderItemModal]()

func itemsDownload(items: Array<Any>) {
    orderItems = items as! [OrderItemModal]
}
```

and viewDidLoad:

```
let bmsOrder = DownloadOrderModal()
bmsOrder.delegate = self
bmsOrder.downloadItems()
```

this is the JSON result:

```
(
    {
    "deptname" = "Production";
    "staffname" = Warehouse;
    "status" = 1;
    "userid" = ware;
})
```

This the the search bar code

```
    filterArray = orderItems.filter( { ($0. staffname) (of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) })
```

And finally, this is the error:

Cannot assign value of type '[OrderItemModal]' to type '[String]'

Ultimately, I will populate the data into a table.

Comment: What's with the `as! (Any) -> Bool) as! [String]` ? That definitely should not be there.

Comment: And why use `NSString`? This is Swift. Stick to Swift strings.

Comment: this have been done by Xcode auto-complete. I have done that in order to get rid of the error.    The console said Cannot convert value of type '(OrderItemModal) -> Bool' to expected argument type '(Any) -> Bool'

Comment: You need to show how `orderItems` is declared. And why are you using `NSArray` instead of a proper Swift array?

Comment: OK, I changed to statement to // var orderItems = [OrderItemModal]()

Comment: Your latest edit doesn't match the code in my answer and as I stated, you also need to change `filterArray` from `[String]` to `[OrderItemModal]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues. It seems that `orderItems` is an `NSArray` array of `OrderItemModal` values. The first thing you need to do is to stop using `NSArray` and use a Swift array of the proper type. In this case it should be `[OrderItemModal]`. You will need to ensure `filterArray` is also declared as `[OrderItemModal]`.

The result of a filter on such an array will be an array of `OrderItemModal` but you are attempting to force cast the result as an array of `String`.

You are also force-casting the closure to be `(Any) -> Bool`. There's no need for that.

And lastly, you are needlessly using `NSString`. Stick with `String`.

All you need is:

```
filterArray = orderItems.filter { (item) -> Bool in
    return item.staffname.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
}
```

Even simpler:

```
filterArray = orderItems.filter { $0.staffname.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
```

Comment: Correct. Thanks for the Answer. In the 'item.staffname.range'. It could not look up the model. It returned like 'Value of type 'Any' has no member 'staffname'

Comment: Are you saying that the code in my answer is giving you an error? If so, please update your question showing how `orderItems` is declared.

Comment: it replied: Value of type 'Any' has no member 'staffname'

Comment: As I said, you need to change `orderItems` from `NSArray` to `[OrderItemModal]`. Don't use `NSArray` in Swift.

Comment: finally, I changed all NSArray to Array, then it said...Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'.

Comment: You need to put details in your question. There is no context to what you just stated in your comment.